# c# webrequest json file missing element value

Tags: c#, json, missing-data

I'm trying to download this json file to read out some data:
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.7.2/data/en_US/item.json

My problem is now that somehow always the values in the tags attribute is missing.

I already used different methods to retrieve them used different encodings but nothing helped. Also the content length is less than the one which I receive in the browser.

Below are some codes I already tried. As you can see I used the WebClient to download this as a string. Also tried to download it as a file, same result.
Used HttpWebRequest with all header attributes.
Used the HEAD method to receive the content length which is less than in the browser.

I also tried using the `MemoryStream` and the `StreamReader` to get the correct data. Nothing worked.

```
String url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + version + "/data/en_US/item.json";
//String json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
String json = "";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8 ";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Method = "GET";
//Get the headers associated with the request.
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
myWebHeaderCollection.Add("DNT", "1");
myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
HttpWebRequest requestHeader = ((HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url));
requestHeader.Method = "HEAD";
using (WebResponse resp = requestHeader.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine(resp.ContentLength);
}
Stream responseStream;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (responseStream != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);
        StreamReader readStream = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.CharacterSet))
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        }
        else
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
        }

        json = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        readStream.Close();
        //using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        //{
        //    responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        //    json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        //}

    }
}
```

Edit:
Sample Outputs:
Browser: http://pastebin.com/nQBj64L0
C# Client: http://pastebin.com/7a0Gxvcg

Comment: I just tested your code and I'm getting the same result as my chrome.

Comment: Browser: http://pastebin.com/nQBj64L0
C# Client: http://pastebin.com/7a0Gxvcg

Comment: I can confirm, output in code is the same as on Firefox. Which tags attribute are you looking for, since some have a value and others don't

Comment: I'm looking for the tags attribute values. The first one has nothing included thats right, but if you look for the 2.nd one, it includes tags like "Boots" or the next one "ManaRegen"

Comment: Have a look at your two sample JSON's. The one from the URL provided is for version 5.7.2, the one from the JSON you show from your code is from version 5.9.1. If I call version 5.9.1 in the app, then the tags are empty, meaning the API changed and the problem lies not within your code

Comment: Ok guys, sry for that. This is a error on the host side, in all previous versions these elements are filled, maybe they had an export problem. Thank you for your support.